# Azure function doesnt see JSON body passed from Shopify properly

Tags: azure, function, shopify, azure-powershell

I'm building an Azure function app based post checkout process for a shopify shop. This is my first time working within the constraints of functions. The function is powershell based.

so the function was developed locally, to do this, I took a copy of the json body of the webhook (Order/Paid from Shopify) with hookbin which is an awesome tool. I then used postman to fire the body at the local copy of the function when devving it.
This is a snippet of shopifys example:

```
{
  "id": 820982911946154500,
  "email": "jon@doe.ca",
  "closed_at": null,
  "created_at": "2021-02-07T20:48:25+00:00",
  "updated_at": "2021-02-07T20:48:25+00:00",
  "number": 234,
  "note": null,
  ...
}
```

so i worked with that, seemed easy enough. In my powershell I did a fairly standard

```
$RequestBody = $Request.Body | ConvertFrom-JSON
```

then i pick out the things i need.

```
$email_address = $RequestBody.email
```

This doesnt work when i join Shopify and the function together. At the point I collect the body of the request, I don't get the same thing that hookbin did.

when i try to convert the json i get this

```
WARNING: Conversion from JSON failed with error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

so i try to dump the body as $Request.body (before i convert to json) and get this

```
INFORMATION: System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```

so, in summary, i clearly havent got the strict JSON i was expecting.
This is the first few lines of my function.

```
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity

    # $RequestBody = $Request.Body | convertfrom-json
    Write-host $Request.Body
```

am i missing a really obvious step that needs to be done in the function that i didnt need to do when collecting the body with hookbin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the output of

```
Write-host $Request.Body
```

**Output :**

```
INFORMATION: System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```

So looks like you are already having dictionary object (Key-Value pair).

if you have to access value of `email`  key you you can directly access it as `$request.body.email` or `$request.body["email"]`

Before doing the above you could try the below steps first :

To understand what keys are present. Accordingly access them.So you can try doing the `Write-Host  $request.body.Keys` to dump all keys associated with dictionary object.

Comment: this. i realised about the time you posted from searching github for other functions code in ps. i dont know why azure functions collect and convert the JSON for you, but that is what it is doing. Thanks.